# Selecting bootable USB seems to be totally ignored

Tags: dual-boot

I currently have a setup on Debian Stretch and I want to dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04. I'm not very experienced in installing another OS so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

What I've done so far :

- I have downloaded the desktop iso for Ubuntu 16.04.
- Formatted my USB to fat32 and erased everything on it
- Used `dd if=path/to/iso of=/dev/sdb1`
- Using gnome-disks, the USB is on auto-mount and bootable
- Restarted my laptop and pressed F9    (Probook 6470b)

I see in the selection my "Generic USB", after pressing F9 on the start of my laptop. When I select it, it still goes to Debian like if I selected to boot from my hard drive with debian. Prior to using Debian, Ubuntu used to be installed. However, my previous bootable USBs were created on Windows 7 with Zadig. Am I missing something?

Comment: Should it be "of=/dev/sdb" not sdb1?

Comment: Ditto.  You don't need to format media before copying a *device* image to it, "device" being distinct in that it represents a whole block device with filesystem partitions in it (which should be written to `/dev/sdb`, a block device), vs. an image that just contains a filesystem (which would need to be written to `/dev/sda1`, a partition).  Bootable images are always device images, not just single filesystems, although they may contain only one filesystem.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you! Please add an explained answer, I will accept it

Comment: Hard to do at reasonable length... What with terms like device having multiple confused meanings etc etc. So I've no problem if @goldilocks puts his answer even if it so happened that my suggestion was the first. To me the more interesting question is : Could we have kept your "sdb1" approach, and turned on the bootable flag?

Comment: @Rusi No, try `fdisk -l whatever.iso` and you'll see why that can never work.

Comment: @goldilocks Some people have [made it work](https://askubuntu.com/a/971205/358822) If you say that's a lot of work I won't dispute

Comment: Interesting but `isohybrid` is obviously a hack, that doesn't count ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain this in [terms plagarized from myself](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51100/5538).

> People are commonly confused by the difference between three distinct
>   things:
>
> 1. A random access block storage *device* such as an SD card (or HDD).
> 2. A storage *partition* which is a section of a *device*; there may only be one which occupies pretty much the whole thing.
> 3. A *filesystem* which is something used to organize the data on a *partition*. Generally speaking there is a one-to-one correspondence between a filesystem and a partition.

On a certain level 1 and 2 are both regarded as "block devices" by the system, (and, on another, colloquially 2 and 3 are often conflated), but in context they are distinct entities. System images come in two flavours, *device* and *filesystem*.  A *bootable* image is always the former, because it must contain some meta-information about the structure of the filesystem(s) and partition(s) contained in them in a format that that standard PCs etc. can use from boot, and that information is stored on the device but not all of it is in a partition.  The two common formats for this information are *(DOS-)MBR,* a legacy of BIOS based systems, and (much newer), *GPT*, an artifact of UEFI based systems.

With regard to linux device nodes, partitions always have a number as a suffix,<sup>1</sup> like this:

```
/dev/sdb1
        ^
```

Indicating this is the first *partition* on the `sdb` *device*.  Again, remember, you can't boot a partition, so there is nothing you can write to this which will make the device bootable if it is not already.  Moreover, `.iso` files are always device images, and if you copy one onto a partition, it won't be usable.  What you want is the device itself:

```
/dev/sdb
```

When you copy a device image onto this, it is copied from block zero, and will erase any and all information currently on that device, including any of the meta-information about partitions and filesystems created by formatting, meaning there's no point in formatting it in any way first.  Some people recommend this out of superstition (aka. [cargo cult practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) gone wrong), but it won't matter.

---

1. An exception to this would be if you format a device as one big filesystem, in which case it is partitionless, and no good to boot from, but can still be mounted as a single fs.  This is not a normal practice however.